# Set a total based on items ordered, two types, and sometimes one type will not be ordered.

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, I am kicking myself, because I had this giving me a total before, but now, It does not grab ALL items chosen for sale, and it does not total correctly. How do I get this to total correctly. There are two types of products and two tables populating these rows, one type is OrderIn_Id and the other is OrderOut_Id. The products are populating perfectly, just not getting a total, and gives me an error of underfined variable, if a person only chooses one type of product, like the OrderIn_id products, then PriceOut gives an error of undefined variable. Can you help?

```
<?php
echo "<table class='middlecheckOut'> 
<tr>
<td class='td2'><b>Order ID: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Product Name: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Quantity: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Price: </b></td>
</tr>";

if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$display="SELECT * 
    FROM order_instate JOIN in_Product ON 
    order_instate.ip_id = in_product.ip_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row['orderIn_complete'] == "No") {      
echo "<tr>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['ip_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>$" . $row['orderIn_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
 </tr>";
 $priceIn = NULL;
 $priceIn += $row['orderIn_total'];
    }
 }

 if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$display2="SELECT * 
    FROM order_outstate JOIN op_Product ON 
    order_outstate.op_id = op_product.op_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display2)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row2['orderOut_complete'] == "No") {        
echo "<tr>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['op_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>$" . $row2['orderOut_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
 </tr>";
  $priceOut = NULL;
 $priceOut += $row2['orderOut_total'];
    }
 }
echo "</table>";

$subtotal = 0;
$tax = 0;
$gtotal = 0;
$subtotal = number_format($priceIn + $priceOut, 2);
$tax = number_format($subtotal * .074, 2);
$gtotal = number_format($subtotal + $tax, 2);

?>
```

Comment: Also take a look at prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<?php
echo "<table class='middlecheckOut'> 
<tr>
<td class='td2'><b>Order ID: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Product Name: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Quantity: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Price: </b></td>
</tr>";

if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$display="SELECT * 
    FROM order_instate JOIN in_Product ON 
    order_instate.ip_id = in_product.ip_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
$priceIn = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row['orderIn_complete'] == "No") {      
echo "<tr>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['ip_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>$" . $row['orderIn_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
 </tr>";

 $priceIn += $row['orderIn_total'];
    }
 }

 if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$display2="SELECT * 
    FROM order_outstate JOIN op_Product ON 
    order_outstate.op_id = op_product.op_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display2)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

$priceOut = 0;
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row2['orderOut_complete'] == "No") {        
echo "<tr>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['op_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>$" . $row2['orderOut_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
 </tr>";

 $priceOut += $row2['orderOut_total'];
    }
 }
echo "</table>";

$subtotal = 0;
$tax = 0;
$gtotal = 0;
$subtotal = number_format($priceIn + $priceOut, 2);
$tax = number_format($subtotal * .074, 2);
$gtotal = number_format($subtotal + $tax, 2);

?>
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, I was going to write up the same. Set the $priceIn and $priceOut variables to 0 before looping through the result set. This way the variables are locked and loaded even if the resultset is empty or all the records have a orderin/out_complete <> "No".

Comment: That's the first thing I noticed too... but I don't know if there is any more issue in the code apart from that...

Comment: THank you!! That worked perfectly! It drives me crazy that I get so close and can't figure out something that small as too move it outside the while loop. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are declaring the variables `$priceIn` and `$priceOut` only inside of the if blocks and setting them to null each time. If, at any point, one of the if blocks does not equal true, the variable would never get set.

Try setting `$priceIn` and `$priceOut` before you run your while loops. Example:

```
<?php
echo "<table class='middlecheckOut'> 
<tr>
<td class='td2'><b>Order ID: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Product Name: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Quantity: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Price: </b></td>
</tr>";

if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$priceIn = 0;
$priceOut = 0;

$display="SELECT * 
    FROM order_instate JOIN in_Product ON 
    order_instate.ip_id = in_product.ip_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row['orderIn_complete'] == "No") {      
        echo "<tr>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row['ip_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row['orderIn_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>$" . $row['orderIn_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
         </tr>";
         $priceIn += $row['orderIn_total'];
    }
 }

 if (isset($_GET['user_id'])) {     
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['user_id']))  {    
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
} 

$display2="SELECT * 
    FROM order_outstate JOIN op_Product ON 
    order_outstate.op_id = op_product.op_id
    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'; " ; 

$displayResult = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display2)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    if($row2['orderOut_complete'] == "No") {        
        echo "<tr>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_id'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row2['op_name'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>" . $row2['orderOut_quantity'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
        <td class='td2'>$" . $row2['orderOut_total'] . " &nbsp&nbsp</td>
         </tr>";
         $priceOut += $row2['orderOut_total'];
    }
 }
echo "</table>";

$subtotal = 0;
$tax = 0;
$gtotal = 0;
$subtotal = number_format($priceIn + $priceOut, 2);
$tax = number_format($subtotal * .074, 2);
$gtotal = number_format($subtotal + $tax, 2);

?>
```